# Claim.py def load() loading incorrect

Tags: python

I'm having issues with the def load() in the following code:

```
def load():
     claim = {}
     data = open("claim.DB").read().split("\n")
     for a in data:
          claimDB[a.split(",")[0]] = a.split(",")[1:]
     claim.claimDB = claimDB
```

For some reason this line in `def load():`

```
claimDB[a.split(",")[0]] = a.split(",")[1:]
```

Is causing this issue:

```
dictionary changed size during iteration
```

And making the dict do this every time you do claim.load():

{'': [], 'asl97': ['charles', 'donboricua'], 'a': ['s', 'l', '9', '7', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 'l', 'e', 's']}

{'': [], 'a': ['s', '', '', 'l', '', '', '9', '', '', '7', '', '', 'c', '', '', 'h', '', '', 'a', '', '', 'r', '', '', 'l', '', '', 'e', '', '', 's']}

Comment: Instead of bpaste, just paste your code here. Outside links can be deleted or modified.

Comment: Also, you can't iterate over a dictionary or list while changing it.

Comment: I can try to paste it but it's super long.

Comment: Paste the related code only, for example just your `load` function.

Comment: There xD that takes forever to do on ipod.

Comment: Hahaha, now let's see

Comment: I'm  not sure that this has anything to do with your issue, but you're opening your file for writing with the `"w"` access mode, but then you read from it. That should raise an exception, I'd think.

Comment: You can edit the question! Avoid asking the same question again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993103/python-claim-py-error-with-def-load

Comment: claimDB DB stands for database

Comment: Oh the "w" was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if you're already iterating over `claimDB` outside `load()`. The following code:

```
claimDB = dict(x=1)

def load():
    data ="1,2\n2,3".split("\n")
    for a in data:
        # modify claimDB <--- BAD
        claimDB[a.split(",")[0]] = a.split(",")[1:]

# iterate over claimDB <--- OK
for k in claimDB:
    load()
```

Causes `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Presuming this is the case, you'll need to extract the contents of `claimDB`, and THEN loop over it:

```
# iterate over the contents of claimDB; it's safe to modify it now, 
# because .items() copies the contents for the generator; list() makes it python 3 safe.
for k, v in list(claimDB.items()):
    load()
```

Comment: This is a good answer. A lone quibble: In Python 3, `items()` doesn't make a copy of the items, but rather returns a set-like iterable dictionary view object. To get an actual list in Python 3, you'd need `list(claimDB.items())`.

Comment: Im so lost xD im sorry